Is it possible in Delphi to pass a general parameter to a function and get detailed information about its type and value?
I want to implement a function that accepts a general parameter and provides detailed information about the parameter, such as its type, value, and if it's an object, its properties.
For example, I would like to pass a variable like this:
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'Hi';
  ShowMessage(GetInfo(s)); // Expected output: s: string = 'Hi'
  ShowMessage(GetInfo(Label1.Caption)); // Expected output: (Label1: TLabel).Caption: string = 'First name:'
  ShowMessage(GetInfo(pb1.Position)); // Expected output: (pb1: TProgressBar).Position: Integer = 70
  ShowMessage(GetInfo(Edit1.Font.Color)); // Expected output: ((Edit1: TEdit).Font: TFont).Color: TColor = 16729702
end;

Is it possible to implement a function like GetInfo that understands the parameter and provides such output?
I attempted to use RTTI (Run-Time Type Information) for this, but I couldn’t achieve the expected result. Specifically, I want to retrieve the type, name, and value of the variable or property passed to the function.
Can anyone suggest how to implement this, or provide an example that would work in Delphi?

No. And you're also not passing Label1.Caption but instead the evaluation of it, which effectively is a String only. At no point you're able to know the name of an evaluation - you can get the class name of an object, but not its variable name. What were your actual attempts with RTTI - why isn't code of yours included? Which result should happen with GetInfo( 3+ 4 )?

As mentioned, this GetInfo is an example and if I understand if it is feasible, I could use the same logic in my app which is so complicated to (simplify it and) bring it here. If it is not feasible, I have to change the logic of my app which would also be a difficult approach.

This kind of functionality requires "compiler magic" which is not available for standard variables. You could get something like this to work for classes, records and enums, using runtime type information (RTTI), but it won't be as easy as calling a function there either.

Yes, you need RTTI, nothing else. What code have you created so far? What's the problem?

I need this technique for more scenarios. One simple idea is to create a custom listbox component where each item is defined by a panel with controls like labels, images, and shapes (as a canvas template) and a data record (as item data). I want to bind each record field to a corresponding control property on the panel. For example:
SpecListBox.Bind(lblFileName, 'Caption', 'FileName') binds the FileName field to the label's caption. However, a cleaner approach would be:
SpecListBox.Bind(lblFileName.Caption, recSpecItem.FileName);
